# keep scroll bar at bottom unless user scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

plz help me with my script.

```
<script>
$ = jQuery;
var currentID = null;
var chatTimer = null;
var scrolled;

function fetch_data() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "select.php",
    method: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#live_data').html(data);
     }
  });
}

function fetch_chat() {

  $.ajax({
    url: "fetch_chat.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      id: currentID
    },
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#chatbox").show();
      $('#messages').html(data);
      $("div.area").show();
      if(!scrolled){
      $('#messages').scrollTop($('#messages')[0].scrollHeight);
      scrolled=true;
      }
    }

  });

}

$(document).ready(function() {

 fetch_data();

  $(document).on('click', '.first_name', function() {
      scrolled=false;
    currentID = $(this).data("id1");
    setInterval(function() {
    fetch_chat();}, 500);
});



  $("#sub").click(function() {

    var text = $("#text").val();
    $.post('insert_chat.php', {
      id: currentID,
      msg: text
    }, function(data) {
      $("#messages").append(data);
      $("#text").val('');
      scrolled=false;
    });
  });

});
</script>
```

when user 'a' sends a message to user 'b' the scroll bar gets updated at a's side and moved to bottom but this doesnt holds true in case of b's side and similarly when when user 'b' sends a message to user 'a' the scroll bar gets updated at only b's side and moved to bottom.